# How to find idle thread count metric in Spring Boot Actuator?

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I'm migrating my application from Jetty to Spring. In Jetty we had `jetty_queued_thread_pool_threads`  and `jetty_queued_thread_pool_threads_idle` .

In the Spring world however, we have a similar `jvm_threads_states_threads` . But I don't see anything that can tell me about the idle threads.

I'd appreciate if someone can share a way to get the idle thread count in Spring actuator metrics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Spring Boot using Jetty as an Embedded Server, you can get the idle threads from the metric `jetty_threads_idle` which is created by the `JettyServerThreadPoolMetrics` class

```
# HELP jetty_threads_idle The number of idle threads in the pool
# TYPE jetty_threads_idle gauge
jetty_threads_idle 1.0
```

The `jvm_threads_states` is showing the number of threads sliced by thread state present in the whole JVM compared to the `jetty_threads_idle` metrics which is describing the Jetty ThreadPool. See the `JvmThreadMetrics` class

Answer (score 0):

Generally, A spring boot application that uses Tomcat as the embedded server has 200 threads. You can verify it by summing up these keys in the actuator

`jvm_threads_peak_threads + jvm_threads_daemon_threads`

Now your question can be why Tomcat has only 200 threads. You can refer this blog which explains this very well

https://alpitanand20.medium.com/tomcat-why-just-200-default-threads-febd2411b904